# Проблема с эмуляторами на WXGA разрешении

Tags: android

Пробовал разные эмуляторы с WXGA разрешением, качал с сайта моторолы эмуль Xoom с андром 3.0, пробовал эмуль гелекси, пробывал стандартный эмуль с WXGA, везде одна проблема, приложение некорректно отображается, будто разрешение 320х480.

Вот скриншот (закрасил само окно прила белым цветом, но суть не в этом, смотрим на размеры приложения в окне)

[image]

Comment: А Layout Width и Layout Height установлены в какие значения для главного лэйаута?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Проблема решается добавлением android:targetSdkVersion="4" в uses-sdk.